# Nodejs instagram in _request SyntaxError: Unexpected token < occurred

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

Hi I'm new to nodejs so I using the npm library [instagram-node-lib](https://github.com/mckelvey/instagram-node-lib)... I was using this for long time and tested it works correctly before but I receive an error from the terminal.

```html
 in _request
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < occurred: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="facebook">
  <head>
    <title>Facebook | Error</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <style>
      html, body {
        color: #141823;
        background-color: #e9eaed;
        font-family: Helvetica, Lucida Grande, Arial,
                     Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }

      #header {
        background: #3b5998
                    url('//static.xx.fbcdn.net/images/logo-fb-trans-92x20.png')
                    center 11px no-repeat;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #133783;
        display: block;
        height: 38px;
        position: relative;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 13px;
      }

      #footer {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        color: #9197a3;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 5px 8px 6px 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <a id="header" href="//www.facebook.com/"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="core">
      <h1 id="sorry">Sorry, something went wrong.</h1>
      <p id="promise">
        We're working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can.
      </p>
      <p id="back-link">
        <a id="back" href="//www.facebook.com/">Go Back</a>
      </p>
      <div id="footer">
        Facebook
        <span id="copyright">
          &copy; 2014
        </span>
        <span id="help-link">
          &#183;
          <a id="help" href="//www.facebook.com/help/">Help Center</a>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('back').onclick = function() {
        if (history.length > 1) {
          history.back();
          return false;
        }
      };

      // Adjust the display based on the window size
      if (window.innerHeight < 80 || window.innerWidth < 80) {
        // Blank if window is too small
        document.body.style.display = 'none';
      };
      if (window.innerWidth < 200 || window.innerHeight < 150) {
        document.getElementById('header').style.background = '#3b5998';
        document.getElementById('header').style.height = '8px';
        document.getElementById('back-link').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('help-link').style.display = 'none';
      };
      if (window.innerWidth < 200) {
        document.getElementById('sorry').style.fontSize = '16px';
      };
      if (window.innerWidth < 150) {
        document.getElementById('promise').style.display = 'none';
      };
      if (window.innerHeight < 150) {
        document.getElementById('sorry').style.margin = '4px 0 0 0';
        document.getElementById('sorry').style.fontSize = '14px';
        document.getElementById('promise').style.display = 'none';
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

is there a way to rectify this error shown from the terminal?

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/mckelvey/instagram-node-lib/issues/21).

Comment: Is Instagram API giving a 503 response happening from the facebook web servers and its just a temporary? When I restart the terminal and run back the npm library, its working back fine, but not sure when will it happen again...

Comment: I think it'll happen randomly.